# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory php -sqlite3

Tags: php, sqlite

my code php , torneo.db file no found

```
<?php
chmod("torneo.db", 0755); //permissions
$result = [
        'ok' => false,
        'message' => 'no se pudo agregar los datos'
    ];

class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('torneo.db'); //here
    }
}



function fetchUrl($uri, $timeout = 10) {
    try {
        $handle = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, false);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, false);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36');

        $response = curl_exec($handle);
        $hlength  = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $body     = substr($response, $hlength);

        if ($httpCode != 200) {
            throw new Exception("HTTP code: " . $httpCode);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $body = false;
    } finally {
        curl_close($handle);
    }

    return $body;
}



$data = trim($_GET['nombredeinvocador']);
$id = preg_replace('/\s+/', '%20', $data);
$pos = false;
//require_once("acentos.php");

try{
    $url = "https ://www.l eagueofgraphs.com/es/summoner/lan/" . urlencode($id);
    $page = fetchUrl($url);
    if(!$page){
        throw new Exception("Error al obtener la pagina");
    }

    $findme = $id;
    $pos = strpos($page, $findme);
    if($pos === false){
        throw new Exception("Invocador no encontrado");
    }
}catch(exception $ex){
    $result['pageError'] = $ex->getMessage();
}




if ($pos === false) {

   die(json_encode($result));
   
   
} else {

    try {
        //para los graciosos que no quieren colocar su pais
        $opciones = array("argentina", "bolivia", "brasil", "chile", "colombia", "costa_rica", "cuba", "ecuador", "el_salvador", "guatemala", "haiti", "honduras", "mexico", "nicaragua", "panama", "paraguay", "peru", "republica_dominicana", "uruguay", "venezuela");
if ( in_array($_GET['pais'], $opciones)) {
   $pais = $_GET['pais'] ;
} else {
    $pais = "Maricolandia";
}

    
$db = new MyDB();

$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO participantes (nombrereal, nombredeinvocador , pais) VALUES (:nombrereal, :nombredeinvocador ,:pais)");
$statement->bindValue(':nombrereal', $nombrereal);
$statement->bindValue(':nombredeinvocador', $nombredeinvocador);
$statement->bindValue(':pais', $pais);

try {
  $statement->execute();
  if($db->lastErrorCode() == 0){
    $result['id'] = $db->lastInsertRowID();
    $result['ok'] = true;
    $result['message'] = 'Se ha registrado correctamente.';
    echo $result['message'];
}
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
      $result['codeError1'] = $e->getCode();
            $result['codeError2'] = $statement->errorCode();
            if($e->getCode() == 1062 or $statement->errorCode() == 23000){
                $result['message'] = 'El invocador ya se encuentra registrado';
            }else{
                $result['message'] = $e->getMessage();
            }
  }

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        //echo $e->getMessage(); 
        $result['message'] = $e->getMessage();    
    }

    }

?>
```

I have the error that I indicated in the title, even giving superuser permission to be able to manage it, I don't understand what is wrong. the driver Sqlite or extension is available, i used that when using php info.

same directory and can't find it...

[Sqlite3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh8tS.png)

[Sqlite3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Loh.png)

[Sqlite3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tXsZ.png)

[Sqlite3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYqMN.png)

[php file exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrm1M.png)

Something curious is that I tried to use it in another file to test and if I can read the file and the information it contains

I even used the php function to check if the file existed and if it is there
the result of my search in my torneo.db file

chaoticsystem Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh8tS.png) => chaoticsystem [nombrereal] => chaoticsystem [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Loh.png) => chaoticsystem [nombredeinvocador] => chaoticsystem [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tXsZ.png) => venezuela [pais] => venezuela )

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that there were two files called connect.php, one in the directory where the index was and another that I was using but in another folder...